# How to read a file in C from a subdirectory

Tags: c, file, unix

This is driving me crazy. I want to read from a subdirectory (./method/CoyoteAdapter.java.tk.method.514.5.533.5.bk), but my code crashes at fscan (Bus error):

```
void readFrag( int **sequence, int& nTokens, char* fragName )
{
    FILE *file;
    char tmp[200];

    strncpy(tmp, &fragName[2], 198);

    char szWorkingDirectory[PATH_MAX];
    szWorkingDirectory[0] = '\0';
    getwd(szWorkingDirectory);

    printf("Attempting to open %s/%s\n", szWorkingDirectory, tmp);
    file = fopen(tmp, "r");

    nTokens = 0;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &(*sequence)[nTokens]);

    while(!feof (file))
    {
        fscanf(file, "%d", &(*sequence)[nTokens]);
        ++nTokens;
    }

    fclose(file);
}

// maxFragSizes: Each block has its max frag size
void init( int **seq, int& seqSize, int **sub, int& subSize, int **problemSizesPerBlock, char* fragListName )
{
    FILE *file;
    char line[200];

    int* tokens = new int[THREADS_PER_BLOCK-1]; 
    int nTokens = 0;

    file = fopen(fragListName, "rt");

    while(fgets(line, 200, file) != NULL)
    {
        readFrag( &(*seq), nTokens, line ); 
    }

    fclose(file);

}
```

However, if I copy the file to my directory, it works. I'm on UNIX (Mac OS). Please help!

**Edit: I added the following code, as suggested. The output it ok, but it still doesn't work...**

Comment: What exactly is the `"t"` supposed to do in `fopen`?

Comment: I scoured my man page and I don't see that option. Is it some weird extension? I thought text mode was specified by not including `"b"` (sorry OP, not trying to hijack your thread here)

Comment: Does `fragName` contain the path to the subdirectory where the file is?

Comment: @AVD: I can't find any mention of `t` in either my system's default `fopen(3)` manpage nor my IEEE-supplied `fopen(3posix)` manpage. (of course, `b` is supposed to be a no-op on POSIX-compliant platforms, it is just included for compliance with ISO C.)

Comment: @sarnold may be right - even the MacOSX man pages don't mention `t`: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man3/fopen.3.html

Comment: well it works in my init function. But I'll check if it works without the t

Comment: No, the t does work on Mac Os.

Comment: I remember seeing the `t` somewhere before...ah, the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) `Open in text (translated) mode. In this mode, CTRL+Z is interpreted as an EOF character on input. In files that are opened for reading/writing by using "a+", fopen checks for a CTRL+Z at the end of the file and removes it, if possible. This is done because using fseek and ftell to move within a file that ends with CTRL+Z may cause fseek to behave incorrectly near the end of the file.`

Answer (score 2):

You must have to verify the file pointer. May be file is not found or you don't have sufficient privileges to read it.

```
 file = fopen(fragName, "rt");
 if(file==NULL)
 {
    printf("\nFile not found");
    return 0;
  }
 fscanf(file, "%d", &tmp);
```

Comment: Well, it's a void function so returning 0 won't work but the underlying idea is sound so +1.

Comment: Oh please, not a `"File not found"`, there are a half-dozen reasons why the file couldn't be opened, and `perror(3)` will show you the _right_ reason just as easily: `perror("Error reading fragment file in readFrag");`

Comment: @mieli, don't just put that forward as a given. Explain _how_ you discovered it's not a permissions problem. In any case, checking the return from `fopen` is still a good idea since permissions problems are only _one_ of the reasons it may fail. It's quite possible (if you're running in an IDE) that the directory you _think_ you're in is not actually the directory you _are_ in.

Comment: well, I chmod 777 -R the whole directory.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't checking to see if "file" being returned by fopen() is NULL or not before calling fscanf.  That's why you are crashing.

As to how to open a file, you may want to call getcwd (getwd) and print the result to see if you are in the parent directory that you think you are in.  You probably don't need the "./" prefix in your file path, but I don't think it hurts.

```
void readFrag( char* fragName ) 
{ 
    FILE *file; 
    int tmp; 
    char szWorkingDir[PATH_MAX];
    szWorkingDirectory[0] = '\0';
    getwd(szWorkingDirectory);

    printf("Attempting to open %s/%s\n", szWorkingDir, fragName);

    file = fopen(fragName, "rt"); 
    if (file != NULL)
        fscanf(file, "%d", &tmp); 
} 

int main()
{
    readFrag("method/CoyoteAdapter.java.tk.method.514.5.533.5.bk");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right. This is the output: /Users/mieli/projects/App2/./method/CoyoteAdapter.java.tk.method.514.5.533.5.bk.

Comment: So I decided to add the following code (see edit). But it still doesn't work, and the output is fine!

Answer (score 2):

[AVD is almost right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8752401/377270) -- you need to check your `FILE*` from `fopen(3)` to see if you actually opened the file. But his answer (and [selbie's similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8752403/377270)) both neglect the single most important piece of information: *why the `fopen(3)` failed*.

Try this:

```
void readFrag( char* fragName )
{
    FILE *file;
    int tmp;

    file = fopen(fragName, "r");
    if (!file) {
        perror("Error reading fragment file in readFrag");
        return;
    }
    fscanf(file, "%d", &tmp);
}
```

I also removed the `t` from the mode as I can't find any documentation anywhere that supports its use. I hope that *this* isn't the cause of the problem -- one would hope the libraries would be a bit more rigorous -- but because it is invalid input it certainly could be at fault. (Check your system's `fopen(3)` manpage and *please* correct me if I'm mistaken about your platform.)

Comment: Oh, I see, you've changed the code _drastically_. Does my replacement code work fine? (Or, another way, did _your_ initial code _actually fail_?) The new code you've given is so very different; the error could also be in how you have allocated memory for the `seq` parameter to `init()`, but you don't show that code...

Comment: I'm not sure if "t" is standard or exists on Unix, but on MSDN, it's documented for the visual c++ cmmpiler as: "t - Open in text (translated) mode. In this mode, CTRL+Z is interpreted as an EOF character on input. In files that are opened for reading/writing by using "a+", fopen checks for a CTRL+Z at the end of the file and removes it, if possible. This is done because using fseek and ftell to move within a file that ends with CTRL+Z may cause fseek to behave incorrectly near the end of the file."

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely the value of `seq` that you're passing in to your init function does not point at a pointer to valid memory (either `seq` itself is invalid, or `*seq` is)